# Getting associated data in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this setup in my Table classes

**Icases table**

```
$this->table('icases');
$this->displayField('name');
$this->primaryKey('id');

$this->belongsTo('Clients', [
    'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
]);
$this->hasMany('Documents', [
    'foreignKey' => 'icase_id'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'icase_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
    'joinTable' => 'icases_users'
    ]);
```

**Clients Table**

```
$this->table('clients');
$this->displayField('name');
$this->primaryKey('id');

$this->hasMany('Icases', [
    'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
    'joinTable' => 'clients_users'
    ]);
```

**IcasesUsers Table**

```
$this->table('icases_users');
$this->displayField('icase_id');
$this->primaryKey(['icase_id', 'user_id']);

$this->belongsTo('Icases', [
    'foreignKey' => 'icase_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

In Icases table I have this SQL, which retrieves active and pending case data for related client and the user who is logged in. This works fine until user sets filter to include archived cases as well as active and pending which returns 107077 rows and I am getting a memory error.
Is there anyway to write this sql using contain() and get data in chunks before serving it to user, so that it cross the memory limit?

```
$cases_data = TableRegistry::get('icases')->find('all')
                ->select(['icases.id', 'icases.state', 'icases.client_id', 'icases.name', 'icases.age', 'clients.name'])
                ->innerJoin('icases_users', 'icases_users.icase_id = icases.id')
                ->where($conditions)
                ->innerJoin('clients', 'clients.id = icases.client_id')
                ->group(['icases.id'])
                ->order(['clients.name' => 'ASC', 'icases.name' => 'ASC'])
                ->execute()
                ->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could paginate your result.

See the [Paginator Helper](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html) and [Pagination Component](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html) documentation.

Comment: Hi Rayann can you give me example if using this Paginator helper in Table class please. Because this document doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: You'll need to look at the documentation for the [Pagination Component](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html) as well.